# Return on Textbox1 value based upon two criterias in combobox and label

Tags: excel, vba, userform

hope u're well. Need an expert help after trying a lot without sucess, please.

I have a price list in Sheet1 with 3 columns:

Medical Procedure
Type
Value of Procedure

In a userform, I need to return in Textbox1 the value of the procedure based on the criteria selected in combobox1 (with values that can be found in Medical Procedure column in Sheet1) and the caption in label1 (wich alrealdy is populated with a value that can be encounter in the Type column in Sheet1).

I tried this found here in stackoverflow from the user B Hart (thanks, B Hart!), but I wasn't able to change it to return in a textbox as a numerical value (this vba insert the found value in a listbox instead). Another issue is that the criteria below is in two combobox. I need the two criterias to be in a combobox and another in a label.

```
Private Sub GetCondStrandValue()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim strValue As String

strValue = vbNullString
If Me.ComboBox1.Value = vbNullString Or Me.ComboBox2.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

With Planilha1
    For iRow = 2 To .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        If StrComp(.Cells(iRow, 1).Value, Me.ComboBox1.Value, 1) = 0 And _
         StrComp(.Cells(iRow, 2).Value, Me.ComboBox2.Value, 1) = 0 Then
            strValue = .Cells(iRow, 3).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With

If strValue = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
With Me.ListBox1
    'If you only want a single value in the listbox un-comment the .clear line
    'Otherwise, values will continue to be added
    '.Clear
    .AddItem strValue
    .Value = strValue
    .SetFocus
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @DirkReichel thank you! I edited the question with what I tried above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Private Sub combobox1_Change()

    Dim lastRow As Integer

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Me

        For r = 2 To lastRow

            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1) = .ComboBox1.Value And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2) = .Label1.Caption Then
                .TextBox1.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3)
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness! I tried, but an error 438 is appearing. I placed this code under Private Sub combobox1_Change(), maybe is that? I want it to be executed when combobox1 have a selected value. Sorry for the lack of knowledge!

Comment: Try changing 'Activesheet' to 'Sheets("Sheet1")' or wherever your objects are. If things are on different sheets, you'll have to remove the With block and prefix '.Cells' (anything starting with a dot), etc. with the correct sheet names (or UserForm names). I would also check your object names, "ComboBox1", etc. Also, my code assumes your data is in columns A:C.

Comment: I amended the second part of my code to fit your requirements.

Comment: THANK YOU, @Chris Mack! I was getting another error, but managed to solve it by adding the name of the userform in front off .ComboBox1 and . Label1 and .Textbox1! Thanks for your time again

Comment: Sorry, that's me, I somehow picked up 'Planilhal' as the name of the UserForm. :) I will correct the code. Thanks